# Azure storage queue polling stops after connectivity issues

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I'm experiencing intermittent `503 Service Unavailable` from azure storage.

Webjobs runner hosted as a top shelf service. Due to the fact that I used `JobHost.Start()` instead of `JobHost.RunAndBlock()` every time I get 503 from azure storage, service ends up in a corrupted stopping state.

When I switched to `JobHost.RunAndBlock()` using instead service is running continuously now but after 503 exception queue trigger stops polling queues.

I use standard azure queue trigger bindings. No manual setup.

Anyone experienced similar behaviour? How to recover from such connectivity errors?

Comment: You mean your "queue" couldn't execute the trigger, so did you check the running log, could you share more information or code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **C#** for your web job, I think using something like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) or [Enterprise Library's Transient Fault Handling Application Block](https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore) to implement retry logic for when an occasional error occurs while using an **Azure** service, as you might be hitting a throttling thresholds (resource limit per your selected service tier).

Hope it helps!